# Validation on Model property is not generating error message for string length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

Hoping someone can help with my query.

Trying to add phone number validation using attributes on model property as below -

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Format")]
[StringLength(14, Minimum Length = 10, ErrorMessage = "Phone number must contain 10 numeric digits")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A phone number is required.")]
```

The regular expression works fine but when I just enter number as "123", I expect to get error message for String Length but instead it displays message from regular expression.

Question - Is there a way to order the validation attributes? If not then whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Might be easier to just change the error message from "Invalid Format" to "Phone number must be in the format (000)000-0000". Have you tried changing the order of the attributes?

Comment: Yes, the error message is actually - Phone number must be formatted as (XXX) XXX-XXXX or XXX-XXX-XXXX

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the order but no luck

Comment: try to create a custom attribute an give order [MyCustomAttribute(Order=1)]

Comment: I thought that is for server side validation and not client side.